# Redundant use of :- in Bash?

Tags: bash, syntax, parameter-expansion

I have this code inside a function:

```
local var="$1"
local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
local def="${2:-}"
if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
    echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
    exit 1
fi
```

What is the role of `:-` here? Isn't it redundant? To be specific, could we not write the if statement this way?

```
if [ "${!var}" ] && [ "${!fileVar}" ]; then
```

How does it help to have an empty "word" on the right side of `:-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The `:-` construct in indirect parameter expansion prevents the script from failing when run with `set -u`.

Here is an example:

```
set -u
var=x
[[ ${!var:-} ]] && echo This works
[[ ${!var} ]]   && echo This should fail
echo "This should print only when run without 'set -u'"
```

which gives this output:

```
line 6: !var: unbound variable
```

If the same statements are run without `set -u`, we get:

```
This should print only when run without 'set -u'
```

However, this trick wouldn't work in case we are using direct parameter expansion. So,

```
set -u
[[ ${var:-} ]] && echo Does this work
```

still throws the error:

```
tt.sh: line 6: var: unbound variable
```

Comment: It **does** work with direct parameter expansion, it did work when indirect parameter expansion wasn't a thing yet.